# Running a function on several files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to run the same code with many files(different file name in same directory) in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550576/how-to-run-the-same-code-with-many-filesdifferent-file-name-in-same-directory)

I have written a function with definition:

```
function deleteEmpty(fileName)
```

Normally when I want to execute the function, in the command window I type:

> ```
> >> deleteEmpty('C:\Documents and Settings\matlab\**myFile**.xls')
> ```

However, I have many files that need to be run through this function.  Does that mean I need to copy and paste the filename and execute the function each time?

Is there any faster way or code to process all my files?

Comment: how have you stored all your filenames? As a struct? As a cell? Plain text file?

Comment: the filenames are stored as .xls file type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a convenient solution to call your function on several files:

```
%# build a list of file names with absolute path
fPath = uigetdir('.', 'Select directory containing XLS files');
if fPath==0, error('no folder selected'), end
fNames = dir( fullfile(fPath,'*.xls') );
fNames = strcat(fPath, filesep, {fNames.name});

%# process each file
for i=1:length(fNames)
    out = deleteEmpty(fNames{i});
end
```

Comment: Thanks Amro...just comments to remove 'out='..the code run well for me..cheers...

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to do this would be to create a wrapper function (or script), which would access the file names in the xls file, and iterate through each of them, running `deleteEmpty` for each filename.

See in particular [xlsread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
%Create the paths to each file as a cell array
path = {'c:', 'Documents and Settings', 'matlab'};
fileNames = {'foo.xls', 'bar.xls', 'baz.xls', 'quux.xls'};
fullFileNames = cellfun(@(f) fullfile(path{:}, f), fileNames, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Loop over files, calling deleteEmpty for each. 
cellfun(@deleteEmpty, fileNames);
```